# how to bypass popup blocker in safari

Tags: javascript, firefox, safari

I have the following code that causes Safari/Firefox to show a popup blocker

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = "/ex/pricing?code=" + code;
link.target = "_blank";
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

Is there a way to open a new link in a new window using javascript without triggering popup blockers.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).

```
window.open('/ex/pricing?code=' + code, '_blank');
```